# ZipException: invalid LOC header when SCPing JSP with jQuery to remote tomcat7

Tags: jquery, jsp, scp, tomcat7

I'm making an easy, little JSP-project using some jQuery for the javascript. When I deployed my project to my webserver via SCP before I used jQuery, there seemed to be no problem. Since I added the jQuery, each time I SCP the .war-file to my tomcat7-server, the server crashes with the following exception: "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)" When I shutdown and restart my tomcat, I can access the project on the webserver again.

It seems it's only crashing when I edit something in the javascript. If I change JSP-stuff, there is no problem.

I tried commenting out my JavaScript-files and then the server doesn't crash. This is pretty annoying since I have to restart the server each time after SCPing. Anyone knows WHY the server crashes when I add the jQuery?